# tkinter Multiple Buttons - Create a variable that is then imported to another executed script

Tags: tkinter, button

I'm creating a `tkinter` box with two buttons that execute two different commands:

- First command is meant to create a variable that can be imported to another script
- Second command is meant to execute that second script

[image: Screenshot]

Code here:

```py
import tkinter as tk
 
master_window = tk.Tk()
master_window.geometry('300x100')
master_window.title('Title')
string_variable = tk.StringVar(master_window)
 
label = tk.Label(master_window, text='Enter Date (YYYYMM): ')
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
 
entry = tk.Entry(master_window, textvariable=string_variable)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
 
def date_variable():
    global YYYYMM
    YYYYMM = string_variable.get()

def run_p():
    exec(open(r'filename.py').read())
 
button = tk.Button(master_window, text='Select Date', command=date_variable)
button2 = tk.Button(master_window, text='Create File', command=run_p)
button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
button2.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
 
master_window.mainloop()
```

When I execute the script below, I then enter a date variable, click 'Select Date' in the attempt to create the date variable. I then click 'Create File' to execute the script.

The `tkinter` window then reappears the same as before. Then, when I run through the same process, the program works perfectly the way it's meant to do.

The question is - why doesn't it work the first time? Why does the `tkinter` box reappear and then it works the second time that the date variable is entered?

The script that the run_p() command calls includes this line to import the YYYYMM variable:

```
from thiscodefile import YYYYMM
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `global YYYYMM` isn't doing anything here and can be removed

Comment: Since you have used `exec()` to execute the code loaded from the file, you don't need to call `from filename import YYYYMM` inside `filename.py` because `YYYYMM` and the code loaded are in the same scope.